# Como puedo comparar un dato de una api con uno nuevo cuando la api se actualice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

tengo un problema de logica en un codigo, el problema es que cuando consumo una api y su lenght sea 20,quiero que cuando llegue un dato nuevo y sean 21 el nuevo dato se compare con el anterior para devolver un true y se ejecute algo.
Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```js
const [Personas, setPersonas] = useState([])
    
    useEffect(() => {
        getPersonaAlert()
        .then(alertas =>{
            setAlertas(alertas)
        })
    },[])
```

Entonces necesito ayuda con la logica para guardar el dato anterior con el nuevo y que se comparen.

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Bienvenido, creo que falta mucha información para poder ayudarte, no logro entender del todo lo que necesitás, quizás te pueda ayudar leer [ask]. Espero puedas mejorar la pregunta para poder ayudarte cuanto antes y evitar que te den votos negativos o cierren tu pregunta.

Comment: Hola Luis, bienvenido, tu pregunta no es clara, podrías intentar reformularla, o en su defecto, agregar un ejemplo de lo que recibes y quieres obtener?, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Answer (score 1):

Lo único que tienes que hacer es guardar el largo en un useState

```
const [lenght, setLenght] = useState(0);
```

hace tu petición a la API y guardas el valor, solo te queda comparar si la nueva información es más larga o corta con el estado

```
async function numbreUtil() {
  const data = await fetch(/* tu info */)

  if (data.length <= length) return
  
  // y aqui añades el codigo que quieres que se ejcute si la condicion es correcta
}
```

No sé si esto es lo que querías saber, porque no es muy descriptiva tu pregunta, espero haberte ayudado